# creating a sequence of number starting or each group of ID

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have  3 source table and have to union them all

Source 1:

```
Id   name  car   
-------------------
1    aaa    BMW   
1    aaa    Porche     
1    aaa    Nissan
2    bbb    Nissan
2    bbb    Honda
```

Source 2:

```
Id   name  car   
-------------------
1    aaa    Camry
```

Source 3:

```
Id   name  car   
---------------------
1    aaa    Honda   
1    aaa    Ford     
2    bbb    Buick
```

Now I want to combine them all and insert into a table with a sequence. this sequence will have incremental value repeating for each ID.

Target table:

```
Id   name    car   sequence
--------------------------------
1    aaa    BMW        1
1    aaa    Porche     2 
1    aaa    Nissan     3
1    aaa    Camry      4
1    aaa    Honda      5
1    aaa    Ford       6
2    bbb    Nissan     1
2    bbb    Honda      2
2    bbb    Buick      3
```

I know I have to use `row_number()` and partition by but unable to capture the sequence with Union with this function. However, I can insert them in temp table and  create another temp table with `row_number`, it works fine.

I unable to update the column with `row_number()` as well. I wanted to know if there is direct approach with union or if I can update the target table?

Comment: Do you really have information stored like this. Will you create a new table when new source is added. There should be a single table with a source column to identify the source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I entirely understood your problem, but this would select the sequence IDs using `ROW_NUMBER` for the union of three tables:

```
;WITH ct AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1,'aaa','BMW'),(1,'aaa','Porsche'),(2,'bbb','Nissan'),(2,'bbb','Honda')) AS T(id,name,car)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1,'aaa','Camry')) AS T(id,name,car)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1,'aaa','Honda'),(2,'bbb','Buick')) AS T(id,name,car)
)
SELECT
    *,
    rn=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY car)
FROM
    ct;
```

Which results in:

```
╔════╦══════╦═════════╦════╗
║ id ║ name ║   car   ║ rn ║
╠════╬══════╬═════════╬════╣
║  1 ║ aaa  ║ BMW     ║  1 ║
║  1 ║ aaa  ║ Camry   ║  2 ║
║  1 ║ aaa  ║ Honda   ║  3 ║
║  1 ║ aaa  ║ Porsche ║  4 ║
║  2 ║ bbb  ║ Buick   ║  1 ║
║  2 ║ bbb  ║ Honda   ║  2 ║
║  2 ║ bbb  ║ Nissan  ║  3 ║
╚════╩══════╩═════════╩════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

simple and lazy way as it looks:
Create a temp table and store your date as follows

```
create table #Temp
(
Id int,
Name nvarchar(50),
Car nvarchar(50)
)
insert into #Temp select * from Source1
insert into #Temp select * from Source2
insert into #Temp select * from Source3
select ID, Name, Car,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Id Order by Id)  as sequence  from #Temp
--OR
--select ID, Name, Car,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Id Order by Id)  as sequence into #Result  from #Temp
--select * from #Result
--OR
--select Id, Name, Car,
--  Row_Number( ) over ( partition by Id order by Id ) as Sequence from
--  (
--select Id , Name, Car from Source1 union all
--select Id , Name, Car from Source2 union all
--select Id , Name, Car from Source3
--) as Result
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to have a specific order of rows within tables.  That allows the results to vary.  So it goes.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Source1 as Table ( Id Int, Name VarChar(3), Car VarChar(10) );
insert into @Source1 ( Id, Name, Car ) values
  ( 1, 'aaa', 'BMW' ), ( 1, 'aaa', 'Porsche' ), ( 1, 'aaa', 'Nissan' ),
  ( 2, 'bbb', 'Nissan' ), ( 2, 'bbb', 'Honda' );
select * from @Source1;

declare @Source2 as Table ( Id Int, Name VarChar(3), Car VarChar(10) );
insert into @Source2 ( Id, Name, Car ) values
  ( 1, 'aaa', 'Camry' );
select * from @Source2;

declare @Source3 as Table ( Id Int, Name VarChar(3), Car VarChar(10) );
insert into @Source3 ( Id, Name, Car ) values
  ( 1, 'aaa', 'Honda' ), ( 1, 'aaa', 'Ford' ), ( 2, 'bbb', 'Buick' );
select * from @Source3;

-- Unstable query.
select Id, Name, Car,
  Row_Number( ) over ( partition by Id order by TableId ) as Sequence
  from (
    select 1 as TableId, Id, Name, Car from @Source1 union all
    select 2, Id, Name, Car from @Source2 union all
    select 3, Id, Name, Car from @Source3 ) as Edgar
```